# Delphi - Extending Indy components in push method

Tags: delphi, push, imap, indy

I need to build mail server using IMAP4. It should "push" mails to client when is connected. I use Delphi XE6 and Indy 10.6.0.5122 that doesn't support IMAP IDLE. Is there any possibility to equip my Indy components in "push" method? If not, then can i substitute "push" for periodic asking server if new mails exist, or it's bad idea?
Thanks for every helpful answer!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 5):

Like you said, [Indy does not currently support `IDLE`](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/147), but you should be able to implement it manually with some extra work.

On the client side, call `TIdIMAP4.IOHandler.WriteLn()` to send an `IDLE` command and `IOHandler.ReadLn` to read its reply (I'm not sure if `TIdIMAP4.SendCmd()` would work in this situation), then start a timer/thread to read inbound data until you turn `IDLE` off.

On the server side, add an entry for `IDLE` in the `TIdIMAP4Server.CommandHandlers` collection and assign an `OnCommand` handler to it to send a reply, then you can push entries to the client socket when needed until the client turns off `IDLE` (with a `DONE` command or closing the socket).

I don't have a code example.  Read [RFC 2177](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2177.txt) for the full detail of how `IDLE` works.

Comment: Thank You very much, it's quantum jump in my work. Have u got some code examples of functional server which using TIdIMAP4Server component?

Comment: @WojciechPawłowski no, I do not

Comment: Ok, i've got one more question. Have You got any experience with "EAGetMail POP3/IMAP4 Component" made by emailarchitect? If yes, then what is better option - extend Indy or use their not free components?